# query with LEAST returning multiple rows in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

When I ran the below query in Oracle 11g

```
SELECT least(val)
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS val
    FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS val
    FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS val
    FROM dual
);
```

I was expecting a single row but it is returning multiple rows. please help me out where exactly my understanding is going wrong..

Comment: you mean min(), least ist not an aggregation-function, it is used for i.E. getting the least value of some columns: least(a,b,c)

Comment: Repeating what Turo and Tim said, in slightly different words: If you have a table with 3 columns and 100 rows, `select least(col1, col2, col3)` will return 100 rows, one column; in each row, the least of the values in the three columns IN THAT ROW will be returned. Similarly (but not as intuitive) - `least(val)` means, FOR EACH ROW return the least value among the set of a single value, the `val` from that row. Obviously, the "least" of a set with a single element is that element. `least(1, 3, 5)` is 1; `least(8)` is 8! Similarly, `least(val)` is simply `val` - FROM THAT ROW.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle's `LEAST` function returns the least value in a list of expressions, e.g. `LEAST(1, 2, 3)` would return `1`.  So `LEAST` could be used to find the minimum value across a collection of *columns*, e.g. `LEAST(col1, col2, col3)`.  What you are seeing is to be expected, i.e. you are getting back three records with the smallest value of each record.

Instead, if you want the minimum over an aggregate of *rows*, then you should be using `MIN`, e.g.

```
select min(val)
from
(
    select 1 as val from dual union all
    select 2 from dual        union all
    select 3 from dual
);
```